# Array Access Globally in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I create a global node in Roku like `m.global = screen.getGlobalNode()` and add interface tag in xml file like below.

```
<interface>
    <field id="GlobleURL" type="array"/>
</interface>
```

and I use in brs file directly `m.top.GlobleURL.Push("Nik's")` Its Generates a error. Is their any solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assigning the values to array--**

In your case, most probably you will be getting error "*Interface not a member of BrightScript Component*". You are facing this issue because of trying to push an element to an array whose length is undefined. So try

```
m.top.GlobalURL = ["Nik's"]
```

instead of "*Push()*" function.

**Alternatively,** if you want to use "*Push()*" function or there is any dependency in your code for adding values dynamically to an array, you can try below approach in your "**.brs*" file--

```
m.GlobalURL = createObject("roArray", 2, true) ' 2 is initial size of array, and "true" defines that array can be resized to accommodate more elements as and when required
m.GlobalURL.Push("val1")
m.GlobalURL.Push("val2")
m.GlobalURL.Push("val3")
```

After this assign the "*m.GlobalURL*" to "*m.top.GlobalURL*" as --

```
m.top.GlobalURL = m.GlobalURL
```

*As commented in previous answer you can't create your own global node, and this is not sufficient to access the array globally.*

**Accessing array globally--**

To access the array globally try something like this--

```
m.global = screen.getGlobalNode()
  m.global.addFields({  
  GlobalURL : [],  
  })
```

Whenever your code is modifying the "*m.top.GlobalURL*", add below code to update the value in global array-

```
m.global.AddReplace("GlobalURL" ,m.top.GlobalURL)
```

After that you can access the "*GlobalURL*" array anywhere in your application as--

```
m.global.GlobalURL
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

As [SDKDocs](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifrosgscreen.md#getglobalnode-as-rosgnode) says, *getGlobalNode()* returns a node, that was already static created. You cannot create your own global node, and then get it using *getGlobalNode()*.
If you want access it from anywhere, you can get it via *getGlobalAA().global*.